# How can I copy a file from a Unix server?

Tags: unix

I have a bunch of files with the extension .dot on a unix server.

These files will need to be saved into either a flash drive or windows hard drive.

I am not very familiar with unix, and thus do not know the commands very well.

It would be great to copy all .dot files at once but if not possible, then one at a time would be great.

Comment: While this is tagged C#/VB, I believe this should be asked over at superuser -- removing the "programming language" aspect will reveal different tools/approaches/protocols to make this possible: SMB/NFS, SCP/SFTP/FTP, HTTP/WebDAV, and the list goes on... I would recommend SCP or SFTP myself (via mingw/cygwin/putty, etc.), but...

Comment: Do you want to do this from a .net language or from the command line?

Comment: I would prefer a .net language since that's what I am more familiar with but if command line is easier and I can understand how to use, that would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot John.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the simplest ways would be to install [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) on your windows machine. Login to the unix server from your windows machine using WinSCP. Once logged in you can drag and drop file from unix to windows and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Unix cp command to copy. For instance:

```
cp *.dot /mount/flash
```

More information on the cp command:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp_(Unix).

To mount your flash drive:
1. Log in as root or use the su command to switch to it
2. Type `mkdir /mount/flash` (this will create a directory for the flash drive)
3. Type `mount /dev/sda1 /mount/flash` (this will mount the flash drive to the directory you created)

After using the flash drive, remember to unmount it with the following command, to avoid any possible data loss.  `umount /mount/flash`. This is similar to the *safely remove hardware* in Windows.

More information on how to mount a flash drive:
http://www.ehow.com/how_6816223_copy-operating-system-flash-drive.html

Comment: Could you post on how to mount a flash drive more? Generally we prefer you post information here, as opposed to just links

Comment: Sorry. I updated my answer to provide more information. Hope this helps.

Comment: Good work ;D! +1 for mentioning safely remove